# Comparar numero de registros de dos tablas SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

necesito realizar lo siguiente: comparar el numero de registros de la tabla A con el de la tabla B
ya que si es menor el de la tabla B se realiza otro proceso, pero no logro comprender como hacerlo

la tabla A y B contienen numero de pedido y bodega, contienen el mismo numero de pedido y diferentes bodega destino
la tabla A contiene 9 registros y la B solo 2

como puedo comparar si contienen el mismo numero de registro?

```
    select count(distinct p1.bodega) from tablaA p1 where p1.numpedido = 12345678 <> 
(select count(distinct p0.bodega) from tablaB p0 where numpedido = 12345678)
```

Es a lo mas que llegue pero realmente no se como validar cual tiene mas registros

Answer (score 0):

Este query te podria servir, haces un select sobre la tablaA que te traiga solo los registros que no esten en la tablaB haciendo la comparacion por numpedido.

```
 Select p1.bodega,p1.numpedido from tablaA p1
            where p1.numpedido not in
                    (select p0.numpedido from tablaB p0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma, podría ser usando un `FULL OUTER JOIN` con el cual puedes unir ambas tablas y comparar las cantidades de filas de cada una, contando la cantidad de `bodega` distintas:

```
SELECT A.numpedido,
       coalesce(COUNT(distinct A.bodega),0) as Bodega_A,
       coalesce(COUNT(distinct B.bodega),0) as Bodega_B
       FROM TablaA A
       FULL OUTER JOIN TablaB B
            ON A.numpedido = B.numpedido
       WHERE A.numpedido = 112345678 or B.numpedido = 112345678
       GROUP BY A.numpedido
```

Puedes asimismo usar esta consulta, sin filtro para listar múltiples pedidos y agregar luego del `GROUP BY` un:

```
HAVING COUNT(distinct A.bodega) <> COUNT(distinct B.bodega)
```

Para mostrar aquellos dónde difiera la cantidad de `bodega` entre ambas tablas.